# Error in modification on MPU6050_DMP6

Tags: arduino-uno, c++

I made modifications on the original code of DMP6 MPU6050 to make it as I want. I took the standard libraries with it and they are `helper_3dmath.h`, `MPU6050.cpp`, `MPU6050.h`, `MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20.h`, `I2C.cpp` and finally `I2c.cpp`.

I made a main.ino and `get_angles.cpp`, which contains the code that has the function that calculates the angles out of the MPU6050. And a header file `get_angles.h`. I am getting an error that I can't figure out.

My main.ino is:

```C
#include <Wire.h>
#include "get_angles.h"
angles imu ;
MPU6050 mpu;
void setup() {
    Wire.begin();
     TWBR = 24;
     Serial.begin(115200);
     mpu.initialize();
     mpu.setDMPEnabled(true);
     packetSize = mpu.dmpGetFIFOPacketSize();
}

void loop() {
  int yaw,pitch,roll;
  yaw =imu.get_yaw();
  pitch=imu.get_pitch();
  roll=imu.get_roll();
}
```

`get_angles.cpp`

```C
#include "get_angles.h"
int angles::get_yaw() {
  MPU6050 mpu;
  mpuIntStatus = mpu.getIntStatus();
  fifoCount = mpu.getFIFOCount();
  // check for overflow (this should never happen unless our code is too inefficient)
  if ((mpuIntStatus & 0x10) || fifoCount == 1024) {
    // reset so we can continue cleanly
    mpu.resetFIFO();
    Serial.println(F("FIFO overflow!"));
    // otherwise, check for DMP data ready interrupt (this should happen frequently)
  } else if (mpuIntStatus & 0x02) {
    // wait for correct available data length, should be a VERY short wait
    while (fifoCount < packetSize) fifoCount = mpu.getFIFOCount();
    // read a packet from FIFO
    mpu.getFIFOBytes(fifoBuffer, packetSize);
    // track FIFO count here in case there is > 1 packet available
    // (this lets us immediately read more without waiting for an interrupt)
    fifoCount -= packetSize;
    mpu.dmpGetQuaternion(&q, fifoBuffer);
    mpu.dmpGetGravity(&gravity, &q);
    mpu.dmpGetYawPitchRoll(ypr, &q, &gravity);
    int yaw;
    yaw=ypr[0] * 180/M_PI;
    return(yaw);
  }
}

int angles::get_pitch() {
  MPU6050 mpu;
  mpuIntStatus = mpu.getIntStatus();
  fifoCount = mpu.getFIFOCount();
  // check for overflow (this should never happen unless our code is too inefficient)
  if ((mpuIntStatus & 0x10) || fifoCount == 1024) {
    // reset so we can continue cleanly
    mpu.resetFIFO();
    Serial.println(F("FIFO overflow!"));
    // otherwise, check for DMP data ready interrupt (this should happen frequently)
  } else if (mpuIntStatus & 0x02) {
    // wait for correct available data length, should be a VERY short wait
    while (fifoCount < packetSize) fifoCount = mpu.getFIFOCount();
    // read a packet from FIFO
    mpu.getFIFOBytes(fifoBuffer, packetSize);
    // track FIFO count here in case there is > 1 packet available
    // (this lets us immediately read more without waiting for an interrupt)
    fifoCount -= packetSize;
    mpu.dmpGetQuaternion(&q, fifoBuffer);
    mpu.dmpGetGravity(&gravity, &q);
    mpu.dmpGetYawPitchRoll(ypr, &q, &gravity);
    int pitch;
    pitch=ypr[1] * 180/M_PI;
    return(pitch);
  }
}

int angles::get_roll() {
  MPU6050 mpu;
  mpuIntStatus = mpu.getIntStatus();
  fifoCount = mpu.getFIFOCount();
  // check for overflow (this should never happen unless our code is too inefficient)
  if ((mpuIntStatus & 0x10) || fifoCount == 1024) {
    // reset so we can continue cleanly
    mpu.resetFIFO();
    Serial.println(F("FIFO overflow!"));
    // otherwise, check for DMP data ready interrupt (this should happen frequently)
  } else if (mpuIntStatus & 0x02) {
    // wait for correct available data length, should be a VERY short wait
    while (fifoCount < packetSize) fifoCount = mpu.getFIFOCount();
    // read a packet from FIFO
    mpu.getFIFOBytes(fifoBuffer, packetSize);
    // track FIFO count here in case there is > 1 packet available
    // (this lets us immediately read more without waiting for an interrupt)
    fifoCount -= packetSize;
    mpu.dmpGetQuaternion(&q, fifoBuffer);
    mpu.dmpGetGravity(&gravity, &q);
    mpu.dmpGetYawPitchRoll(ypr, &q, &gravity);
    int roll;
    roll=ypr[2] * 180/M_PI;
    return(roll);
  }
}
```

`get_angles.h`

```C
#ifndef get_angles_H
#define get_angles_H

#include "I2Cdev.h"
#include "MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20.h"
static   uint16_t packetSize;
class angles {
  public:
    int get_yaw();
    int get_pitch();
    int get_roll();
  private:
    uint8_t mpuIntStatus;
    uint16_t fifoCount;     // count of all bytes currently in FIFO
    uint8_t fifoBuffer[64]; // FIFO storage buffer
    Quaternion q;           // [w, x, y, z] quaternion container
    VectorFloat gravity;    // [x, y, z] gravity vector
    float ypr[3];           // [yaw, pitch, roll] yaw/pitch/roll container and gravity vector
};
#endif
```

The error I am facing:

```
Arduino: 1.6.5 (Windows 8.1), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"

third_iteration.cpp.o: In function `MPU6050::dmpInitialize()':
C:\Users\MOHAME~1\AppData\Local\Temp\build384877420483334776.tmp/MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20.h:325: multiple definition of `MPU6050::dmpInitialize()'
get_angles.cpp.o:C:\Users\MOHAME~1\AppData\Local\Temp\build384877420483334776.tmp/MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20.h:325: first defined here
third_iteration.cpp.o: In function `MPU6050::dmpInitialize()':
C:\Users\MOHAME~1\AppData\Local\Temp\build384877420483334776.tmp/MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20.h:325: multiple definition of `MPU6050::dmpPacketAvailable()'
get_angles.cpp.o:C:\Users\MOHAME~1\AppData\Local\Temp\build384877420483334776.tmp/helper_3dmath.h:56: first defined here
third_iteration.cpp.o: In function `MPU6050::dmpInitialize()':
C:\Users\MOHAME~1\AppData\Local\Temp\build384877420483334776.tmp/MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20.h:325: multiple definition of `MPU6050::dmpGetAccel(long*, unsigned char const*)'
get_angles.cpp.o:C:\Users\MOHAME~1\AppData\Local\Temp\build384877420483334776.tmp/helper_3dmath.h:56: first defined here
third_iteration.cpp.o: In function `MPU6050::dmpInitialize()':
C:\Users\MOHAME~1\AppData\Local\Temp\build384877420483334776.tmp/MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20.h:325: multiple definition of `MPU6050::dmpGetAccel(int*, unsigned char const*)'
get_angles.cpp.o:C:\Users\MOHAME~1\AppData\Local\Temp\build384877420483334776.tmp/helper_3dmath.h:56: first defined here
third_iteration.cpp.o: In function `MPU6050::dmpInitialize()':
C:\Users\MOHAME~1\AppData\Local\Temp\build384877420483334776.tmp/MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20.h:325: multiple definition of `MPU6050::dmpGetAccel(VectorInt16*, unsigned char const*)'
get_angles.cpp.o:C:\Users\MOHAME~1\AppData\Local\Temp\build384877420483334776.tmp/helper_3dmath.h:56: first defined here
third_iteration.cpp.o: In function `MPU6050::dmpInitialize()':
C:\Users\MOHAME~1\AppData\Local\Temp\build384877420483334776.tmp/MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20.h:325: multiple definition of `MPU6050::dmpGetQuaternion(long*, unsigned char const*)'
get_angles.cpp.o:C:\Users\MOHAME~1\AppData\Local\Temp\build384877420483334776.tmp/helper_3dmath.h:56: first defined here
third_iteration.cpp.o: In function `MPU6050::dmpInitialize()':
C:\Users\MOHAME~1\AppData\Local\Temp\build384877420483334776.tmp/MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20.h:325: multiple definition of `MPU6050::dmpGetQuaternion(int*, unsigned char const*)'
get_angles.cpp.o:C:\Users\MOHAME~1\AppData\Local\Temp\build384877420483334776.tmp/helper_3dmath.h:56: first defined here
third_iteration.cpp.o: In function `MPU6050::dmpInitialize()':
C:\Users\MOHAME~1\AppData\Local\Temp\build384877420483334776.tmp/MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20.h:325: multiple definition of `MPU6050::dmpGetQuaternion(Quaternion*, unsigned char const*)'
get_angles.cpp.o:C:\Users\MOHAME~1\AppData\Local\Temp\build384877420483334776.tmp/helper_3dmath.h:56: first defined here
third_iteration.cpp.o: In function `MPU6050::dmpInitialize()':
C:\Users\MOHAME~1\AppData\Local\Temp\build384877420483334776.tmp/MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20.h:325: multiple definition of `MPU6050::dmpGetGyro(long*, unsigned char const*)'
get_angles.cpp.o:C:\Users\MOHAME~1\AppData\Local\Temp\build384877420483334776.tmp/helper_3dmath.h:56: first defined here
third_iteration.cpp.o: In function `MPU6050::dmpInitialize()':
C:\Users\MOHAME~1\AppData\Local\Temp\build384877420483334776.tmp/MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20.h:325: multiple definition of `MPU6050::dmpGetGyro(int*, unsigned char const*)'
get_angles.cpp.o:C:\Users\MOHAME~1\AppData\Local\Temp\build384877420483334776.tmp/helper_3dmath.h:56: first defined here
third_iteration.cpp.o: In function `MPU6050::dmpInitialize()':
C:\Users\MOHAME~1\AppData\Local\Temp\build384877420483334776.tmp/MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20.h:325: multiple definition of `MPU6050::dmpGetGyro(VectorInt16*, unsigned char const*)'
get_angles.cpp.o:C:\Users\MOHAME~1\AppData\Local\Temp\build384877420483334776.tmp/helper_3dmath.h:56: first defined here
third_iteration.cpp.o: In function `MPU6050::dmpInitialize()':
C:\Users\MOHAME~1\AppData\Local\Temp\build384877420483334776.tmp/MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20.h:325: multiple definition of `MPU6050::dmpGetLinearAccel(VectorInt16*, VectorInt16*, VectorFloat*)'
get_angles.cpp.o:C:\Users\MOHAME~1\AppData\Local\Temp\build384877420483334776.tmp/helper_3dmath.h:56: first defined here
third_iteration.cpp.o: In function `MPU6050::dmpInitialize()':
C:\Users\MOHAME~1\AppData\Local\Temp\build384877420483334776.tmp/MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20.h:325: multiple definition of `MPU6050::dmpGetLinearAccelInWorld(VectorInt16*, VectorInt16*, Quaternion*)'
get_angles.cpp.o:C:\Users\MOHAME~1\AppData\Local\Temp\build384877420483334776.tmp/helper_3dmath.h:56: first defined here
third_iteration.cpp.o: In function `MPU6050::dmpInitialize()':
C:\Users\MOHAME~1\AppData\Local\Temp\build384877420483334776.tmp/MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20.h:325: multiple definition of `MPU6050::dmpGetGravity(VectorFloat*, Quaternion*)'
get_angles.cpp.o:C:\Users\MOHAME~1\AppData\Local\Temp\build384877420483334776.tmp/helper_3dmath.h:56: first defined here
third_iteration.cpp.o: In function `MPU6050::dmpInitialize()':
C:\Users\MOHAME~1\AppData\Local\Temp\build384877420483334776.tmp/MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20.h:325: multiple definition of `MPU6050::dmpGetEuler(float*, Quaternion*)'
get_angles.cpp.o:C:\Users\MOHAME~1\AppData\Local\Temp\build384877420483334776.tmp/helper_3dmath.h:56: first defined here
third_iteration.cpp.o: In function `MPU6050::dmpInitialize()':
C:\Users\MOHAME~1\AppData\Local\Temp\build384877420483334776.tmp/MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20.h:325: multiple definition of `MPU6050::dmpGetYawPitchRoll(float*, Quaternion*, VectorFloat*)'
get_angles.cpp.o:C:\Users\MOHAME~1\AppData\Local\Temp\build384877420483334776.tmp/helper_3dmath.h:56: first defined here
third_iteration.cpp.o: In function `MPU6050::dmpInitialize()':
C:\Users\MOHAME~1\AppData\Local\Temp\build384877420483334776.tmp/MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20.h:325: multiple definition of `MPU6050::dmpProcessFIFOPacket(unsigned char const*)'
get_angles.cpp.o:C:\Users\MOHAME~1\AppData\Local\Temp\build384877420483334776.tmp/helper_3dmath.h:56: first defined here
third_iteration.cpp.o: In function `MPU6050::dmpInitialize()':
C:\Users\MOHAME~1\AppData\Local\Temp\build384877420483334776.tmp/MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20.h:325: multiple definition of `MPU6050::dmpReadAndProcessFIFOPacket(unsigned char, unsigned char*)'
get_angles.cpp.o:C:\Users\MOHAME~1\AppData\Local\Temp\build384877420483334776.tmp/helper_3dmath.h:56: first defined here
third_iteration.cpp.o: In function `MPU6050::dmpInitialize()':
C:\Users\MOHAME~1\AppData\Local\Temp\build384877420483334776.tmp/MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20.h:325: multiple definition of `MPU6050::dmpGetFIFOPacketSize()'
get_angles.cpp.o:C:\Users\MOHAME~1\AppData\Local\Temp\build384877420483334776.tmp/helper_3dmath.h:56: first defined here
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Error compiling.

  This report would have more information with
  "Show verbose output during compilation"
  enabled in File > Preferences.
```

Comment: The error, if you read it, doesn't relate to any of those files, it relates to `MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20.h`. Maybe you should have included that file too?  Oh, and `helper_3dmath.h`

Comment: yeah i know that but i declare #include "MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20.h" in my header and in it the declearation of the other like helper_3dmath and the other libraries as i said before in the main post .... and btw that is the original dmp code so .. if i took this libraries and put besides jeff code it will work prefectly  @Majenko

Comment: Well, that i2cdev library code you have to treat with real kid gloves. Mess with it at your peril. The way it's been written breaks all the rules of good coding and the author should be strung up by his danglies. If he'd been in my employ and had written that code I'd have sacked him on the spot. Good luck with messing with it - you're a braver man than I. I'd start by re-writing the whole library suite *properly*.

Comment: i didn't missed with anything i just took his main and put it in cpp and make his decleration in header then called this class i have done in cpp file .... so i didn't miss with anything .... and that why i am really angry ... i didn't do anything to the code just copy and paste and the error is muilti-defination ... anyway thank you @Majenko

Comment: And that's all you really need to do to break it, it's written that poorly.  The whole problem can be summed up in four words: *"Functions in Header Files"*

Comment: ok ... i am in my first steps in coding ... if it is not rudeness can you tell me what i can do to take the original code and don't break it ... thanks in advance and of course make it parts as cpp and header  @Majenko

Comment: You need to split it all apart properly so that the functions aren't in the header files, but instead are in cpp files where they should be.